# Изменение view через DialogFragment/RecyclerViewApadapter/AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-dialog

Приветствую, пытался реализовать настройки, иерархия получилась большая.

У меня в главной активити есть `TextView`, в этой активити я вызываю `DialogFragment`, `DialogFragment` содержит в себе `RecyclerView` который отображает список настроек через свой адаптер. В этом адаптере я реализовал метод `onClick` в котором вызываю `AlertDialog`:

```
 viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
```

Получилось так: `MainActivity/DialogFragment/RecyclerViewAdapter/AlertDialog`

Вопрос: Как мне из моего `AlertDialog`a поменять, например, размер моего `TextView` в главной активити?

Answer (score 2):

Есть [стандартный паттерн](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) взаимодействия фрагмента с `Activity` или другими фрагментами.

Он заключается в том, чтобы во фрагменте должен быть декларирован интерфейс, который имплементируется тем, кто хочет взаимодействовать с фрагментом, типа:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
   //blah-blah

   public interface MyFragmentListener {
       public void onFragmentSomethingHappens();
       public void onFragmentYetAnotherHappens();
   } 
}
```

В `Activity` или другом фрагменте делаем так

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyFragment.MyFragmentListener {
    //blah-blah
    public void onFragmentSomethingHappens() {
         //blah-blah
    }
}
```

Собственно говоря все. При создании адаптера, получить ссылку на фрагмент, это достаточно просто, далее вызываем метод интерфейса фрагмента, по которому в `Activity` что-то происходит - в вашем случае изменение размера `TextView`

Comment: Могли бы вы подробнее объяснить, на примере простых имен, где именно получать ссылку на фрагмент, где вызвать метод. Голова уже совсем не варит, вроде короткий и ясный ответ, не могу сообразить.

Comment: @McDaggen у меня своя политика в отношении ответов - я всегда даю не ответы, а направления для работы. Копи-пейст это не ко мне - это к Гуглу.